# How do I stop the lock pattern from being revealed after I got it wrong?

Tags: security, lock-screens, lineageos

I'm security-minded so my lock pattern is not displayed as I enter it.

By lock pattern, I mean one of these:

[image]

The pattern is revealed after a failed lock attempt. I've been through all the settings I can find but there is apparently no switch for this behaviour.

I am using a rooted HTC One S, LineageOS 14.1 running kernel 3.4.

Comment: "I'm security-minded"... You are unlocked, have a custom ROM and recovery... your security concerns are pretty lopsided. No offense, but anyone who can get physical access to your device can access anything with minimal effort in seconds. I don't think a missed lock screen pattern flashing for an instant should be your biggest security concern if security is really important to you. (Not trying to troll, just make a point that the issue you're trying to solve is not the real security problem)

Comment: IIRC, GravityBox, an Xposed module, has an option that can disable "The red trail on failed lock attempts".

Comment: @CoolGuy: Thanks for input - amended solution

Comment: @acejavelin I don't use this device for anything sensitive, it's my muck-around phone, but it's outrageous that such an idiotic anti-feature is enabled by default.

Comment: Also, my threat model isn't necessarily "someone takes my phone and plugs its into a computer to read everything" because unless the attacker is a spook, I've probably got a bit of time to lock up my bank accounts and email etc. My threat model is more along the lines of "someone looks over my shoulder, picks my pocket, and buys themselves bitcoin, all in the space of a few minutes". Why make it easy?

Answer (score 1):

Your device is rooted , so you could try [Gravity Box Xposed module](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v6-0-0-tweak-box-android-t3251148) has to **disable pattern error** - thanks to Cool Guy's comment

---

That aside, since you are security minded

**Pattern locks are inherently less secure than PIN locks. Why?**

From [Android Security Internals: An In-Depth Guide to Android's Security](https://www.nostarch.com/androidsecurity) by Nikolay Elenkov** ( runs a blog [here](https://nelenkov.blogspot.in/) )

> .... the code for pattern unlock is entered by joining at least four points on a 3×3 matrix. Each point can be used only once (crossed points are disregarded) and the maximum number of points is nine. Internally, the pattern is stored as a byte sequence, with each point represented by its index, where 0 is top left and 8 is bottom right. Thus the pattern is similar to a PIN with a minimum of four and maximum of nine digits, which uses only nine distinct digits (0 to 8). However, *because points cannot be repeated, the number of variations in an unlock pattern is **considerably lower** compared to those of a nine-digit PIN*

(Emphasis Supplied)

**Screenshot of passage [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el6xT.jpg)

If you switch over to PIN , you can protect against *smudge attacks* by scrambling numbers as explained in my answer here either by using an app or Gravity Box Xposed module [Marshmallow - disable unlock touch feedback](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154980/131553)

Comment: My pattern is on a 6x6 matrix and includes jumps between non-adjacent dots. That 3x3 thing shouldn't be the default, but good point.

Comment: Did you try GravitationalXposed module ?

Comment: Xposed doesn't seem to be available for Nougat.

Comment: Oh.. My bad.. Missed that completely